# Why is a C# winform shown different with DPI 150% while opening through cpp project

Tags: c#, c++

I am facing an issue in windows form while opening C# application through cpp project with DPI 150%.

The issue is Controls in a form it truncating and controls sizes are not showing as it is. For example, button size is 23 px but it is showing as 14 px.

I am not facing this issue while opening the same C# application through C# project in 4K monitor. Controls sizes are also coming proper.

Can anyone please suggest what will be the issue and how to resolve it.

Thanks,
Rajesh.

Comment: What happens if the DPI is 100%?

Comment: Disable application scaling? i.e. Go to your build/debug or release folder and make sure the scaling is turned off from application side. You might have to play around with the options but that usually works for me.

Comment: _"while opening C# application through cpp project "_ - can you explain what this means?

Comment: if DPI is 100% it is working fine.@i486

Comment: I need to fix issue in DPI 150% if we disable application scaling then the DPI will 100% right then it wont resolve my issue.@Rietty

Answer (score -1):

What i would guess is that you are using WinForms, which has some problems with HiDpi Scaling. If you are starting your application only as your own project by default it is marked as **DPI Unaware**. This means the application might look pixilated at other than 100% but the layout is ok.

To create a hi dpi enabled WinForm app, is unfortunatley not that easy.

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows)

However when using your components in parts of a larger project where the DPI Mode is set by another part of the System, this can lead to layouut problems.

If its a .NET Project you can fix this by adding the following assembly attribute:

```
[assembly: System.Windows.Media.DisableDpiAwareness]
```

I hope this helps.